# ng-model not working in ui-router nested view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code structure

index.html

```
<body ng-app="jobPortalApp" ng-controller="mainController">
   <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

then following is my homepage.html template

```
<div id=header>
</div>
<div ui-view>
     <input type="text" ng-model="test">Test</input>
     <input type="submit" ng-click="signup()">
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

my angular module file is as follows

```
var jobPortalApp = angular.module('jobPortalApp',['ui.router']);

jobPortalApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home',
            {
                url:'/',
                templateUrl: './templates/homepage.html',
                controller: 'controllerHome'
            })
}).controller('mainController', function(){});
```

following is my home controller

```
jobPortalApp.controller('controllerHome',function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.test="";
     $scope.signup = function() {
         console.log($scope.test);
     }
});
```

Required:
I want the changed value of test in my controllerHome after the user clicks on signup

Problem:

console.log outputs blank and if I remove `$scope.test="";`then outputs undefined. I want the changed value of test in my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually shouldn't bind directly to `$scope` due to issues with prototypal inheritance. When trying to read a value from a child scope, if the value doesn't exist you end up reading from the parent scope. But as soon as you write, you write to the child scope. Does it work if you bind to an object instead?

```
$scope.data = {
    test: ""
};

<input type="text" ng-model="data.test">Test</input>
```

As an alternative, you may also want to look at the `controllerAs` option for your route:

`controllerAs: "ctrl"`

Then in your controller:

`this.test = ""`;

And in your template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.test">Test</input>
```

Comment: thanks this works! I just tested this with my test code.